# Why do my speakers randomly shut off but my headphones work?

Tags: 12.04, sound, music, speakers

Whenever im listening to rhythmbox my speakers will shut off after about 45 seconds and wont come back on until i restart my computer. But my headphones work whenever they shut off. Does anyone know whats going on? I am on a Toshiba Satellite L755-S5248.

Here is a screenshot of `alsamixer`:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of `alsamixer`?

Comment: It will not let me.

Comment: Post a link to it and I will add it for you.

Comment: You can use http://imgur.com or http://postimage.org to post the image, then link to it, and as he says @Seth (or someone else if they see it first) can add the image itself into your question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6Lclsd5.png